# How to show list in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I want to show the list of tickets in my Angular frontend. I mean to show `ticketId` and `place` like on the picture below.

Here is my request from `http://localhost:8080/api/customers`

[image]

Here is the result in `http://localhost:4200/customer`

Unfortunately list of tickets is empty. I don't know how to show it.

[image]

Here is my class `customer-details.component.html`

```
<div *ngIf="customer">
<div>
<label>Name: </label> {{customer.name}}
</div>
<div>
<label>Surname: </label> {{customer.surname}}
</div>
<div>
<label>List of tickets: </label> {{customer.tickets}}
</div>
<span class="button is-small btn-danger"  (click)='deleteCustomer()'>Delete</span>
<hr/>
</div>
```

My class `customers-list.component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers | async" style="width: 300px;">
<customer-details [customer]='customer'></customer-details>
</div>

<div>
<button type="button" class="button btn-danger" (click)='deleteCustomers()'>Delete all</button>
</div>
```

Class `customer.service.ts`

```
export class CustomerService {

private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/customers';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getCustomersList(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
}
```

My class `customer.ts`

```
export class Customer {
customerId: number;
name: string;
surname: string;
tickets: Ticket[];
}
export class Ticket {
ticketId: number;
place: number;
customerId: number;
flightId: number;
}
```

Class `customers-list.component.ts`

```
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {

customers: Observable<Customer[]>;

constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.reloadData();
}

reloadData() {
this.customers = this.customerService.getCustomersList();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the picture of the json response the property is called `ticket`, not `tickets`. So you want to either rename it (since it's clearly a misnomer) or iterate accordingly:

```
*ngFor="let ticket of customer.ticket"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `customer-details.component.html` you have to iterate on your `ticket`.

You can try something like this :

```
<div>
  <label>List of tickets: </label>
  <div *ngFor="let ticket of customer.ticket">
    {{ ticket.ticketId }}
    {{ ticket.place }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's still empty